# How can I code a pop up text box that only appears on mobile devices when the screen is flipped vertically and goes away when flipped horizontally?

Tags: html, css, mobile, popup, user-experience

I want to create a pop up notice that only appears on mobile. I want the message to prompt viewers to flip their device horizontally, and when they do I would like the message to disappear. What would my code for this be?

Comment: I want it to appear automatically when the website first appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can specificially target decvices in portrait mode with CSS queries like the one below:

```
   <div id="pop-up">Turn your device horizontally</div>

     /* Hides pop up when landscape */
     @media only screen 
     and (min-device-width : 375px) 
     and (max-device-width : 667px) 
     and (orientation : landscape) { 
       #pop-up {
       display: none;
       }
     }

     /* Shows pop up when portrait */
     @media only screen 
     and (min-device-width : 375px) 
     and (max-device-width : 667px) 
     and (orientation : portrait) {
       #pop-up {
       display: unset
       }
     }
```

Edit: This jsfiddle is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/jarrodwhitley/gj0dx3zy/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show it on specific width + on landscape per media query like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .notification {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Here a full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <style media="screen">
    body {
      background-color: #666;
    }

    .notification {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      right: 10%;
      left: 10%;
      bottom: 10%;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 769px) and (orientation: landscape) {
      .notification {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="notification">
    Please flip your Phone!
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: marvhock- Thank you so much. I tried it but it just doesn't seem to appear when I try it on mobile still. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try to load just the code from my example above? If yes, it might be that your device has more width than 769px and you have to increase that value. To make sure the issue is really not the max-width, you could remove the "and (max-width: 769px)" from above example and try again.